# HTML not rendering through EJS

Tags: express, ejs

so basically I have a bunch of HTML strings in a MySQL table and I am trying to display then through EJS.

For instance, I have a string that looks like `this is a <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">link</a> with some <code>code</code> next to it`. In my code I try to display it in that way.

```
<%- listOfStrings["myString"] -%>
```

However, as you probably guessed when reading the title, the string seems to be escaped when displaying on the screen.

What's even weirder to me is that I have two tables with such strings, and it works for the first one, while it doesn't for the second one. One difference though, is that the first one is hardcoded, while the second one can be edited through some tool on my website. Encoding is *utf32_unicode_ci* for both tables, if that matters.

For debugging purposes I tried to store the aforementioned strings in a js variable and display them in the console: then it seems like `<`and `>` characters are all escaped for some reason. Is there an explanation to this behavior, and if so how to fix it so that HTML renders correctly?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are using the right ejs script to print out html variable by escaping the html characters (not <%=...%>, did you verified that your second string stored in your database encoded utf32_unicode_ci is kept the html characters ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it :

```
<%=listOfStrings["myString"]%>
```

Comment: the assign character will escape the html characters  <%= ... %>, he should use <%- .... %> to not escape html character